# Magento white page at backend and frontend

Tags: php, error

After customizing some files last week, both the backend and frontend of the site I’m developing for went blank. I have already searched the internet and tried out some possible solutions, but none of them works.

Somehow I can’t manage to show any error message. I already uncommented ini_set(’display_errors’, 1);, changed error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); into error_reporting(E_ALL); and I tried even more possible solutions. 
I also edited the memory to 128M, changed some settings in php.ini, changed local.xml.sample to local.xml. Nothing seems to work..

I seriously have no idea how I can solve this, so that’s why I’m here. I hope someone can help me. If you need more information, please ask, I don’t really know what’s necessary to answer my question.

---

After adding the following lines to index.php I managed to get error messages:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set(’display_errors’, 1); 
ini_set(‘memory_limit’, ’256M’);
```

The error I get is:

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/cheapas/public_html/index.php, line 39
```

Trace:

```
#0 /home/cheapas/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true) 
#1 /home/cheapas/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1246): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader(’Content-Type’, ‘text/html; char...’) 
#2 /home/cheapas/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse() 
#3 /home/cheapas/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php(204): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse() 
#4 /home/cheapas/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(166): Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite->rewrite() 
#5 /home/cheapas/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() 
#6 /home/cheapas/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 
#7 /home/cheapas/public_html/index.php(91): Mage::run(’’, ‘store’) 
#8 {main}
```

Guess what, line 39 is: ini_set(‘memory_limit’, ’256M’);

When I delete this line I get a blank page again, so that doesn’t solve anything. Does anyone have an idea on solving this? Thanks!

---

As you may have understood, I actually can get error messages to show when I force an error by adding an unknown or uncomplete line to my index.php. Somehow there is a problem which doesn’t want to show up.

Comment: I don't suppose you have the code in version control so you can step back to find out which changes caused the break?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Have you checked your apache error log files? Also, what happens if you call "php index.php" from command line?

Comment: Hey simonthesorcerer. This question is over a year old. I wasn't able to resolve the problems I had at the time, so I reinstalled the theme to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Enable developer mode in `index.php`. Be sure you're not using some copy/pasta from a site like a wordpress blog, they are known to add special characters for `'` and `"` on code snippets, judging from the code pasted, these are bad: `‘` & `’`.

Next check `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log`. You can double check via the database by looking at `core_config` and finding the logging values under the `path`:  `dev/log/active`. If it is set to to `0` set it to `1` to enable.

If Magento's not displaying or logging anything, then take a look at your web servers error.log file, as it will offer the most insight, if an exception is occuring above magento. You'll also want to double check your `.htaccess` and web server configuration for the domain.

There also may be a module or some custom code outputting (echo/print/debug/etc.) before hand, causing the error returned.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Enabling developer mode didn't do anything. I checked var/log/system.log but I can't really find an error which causes this and the last error is from 18Apr. I can't find the exception.log file. I don't really understand your part about core_config. Could you explain to me how I can do that? My error.log file in cPanel is empty.

Answer (score 1):

for  headers issue 
in cpanel file manager please add a script as 
output_buffering=on;
would get fixed

Answer (score 0):

The blank screen issue can have different reasons for occurring.

It might be related to web server rewrites issue, should Apache rewrite_module be disabled (unlikely). 
It might be related to writing permissions on your public_html. Try running the following command via ssh console:

```
 chmod -R 777 /var/www/your-root/path
```

Also, restarting Apache can sometimes solve blank screen issues.

*Side question:* can someone confirm that giving 777 permissions is potential security issue?